# pylab.show() did not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run the python code as it is from this website:

http://cvxopt.org/examples/book/rls.html

To show it here:

```
    # Figure 4.11, page 185.
    # Regularized least-squares.
  ....
    pylab.figure(1, facecolor='w')
    pylab.plot(lbnds, alpha1, 'b-', ubnds, alpha2, 'b-')
    kmax = max([ k for k in range(len(alpha1)) if alpha1[k] <
        blas.nrm2(xls)**2 ])
    pylab.plot( [ blas.nrm2(b)**2 ] + lbnds[:kmax] +
        [ blas.nrm2(A*xls-b)**2 ], [0.0] + alpha1[:kmax] +
        [ blas.nrm2(xls)**2 ], '-', linewidth=2)
    pylab.plot([ blas.nrm2(b)**2, blas.nrm2(A*xls-b)**2 ],
        [0.0, blas.nrm2(xls)**2], 'bo')
    pylab.fill(lbnds[-1::-1] + ubnds + [ubnds[-1]],
        alpha1[-1::-1] + alpha2+ [alpha1[-1]], facecolor = '#D0D0D0')
    pylab.axis([0, 15, -1.0, 15])
    pylab.xlabel('||A*x-b||_2^2')
    pylab.ylabel('||x||_2^2')
    pylab.grid()
    pylab.title('Regularized least-squares (fig. 4.11)')
    pylab.show()
```

it is supposed to show the plot after I run `python rls.py` . But nothing appear, any help? Thank you

Comment: what backend are you using?

Comment: The code on that page has "try: import pylab". Perhaps remove the "try" to make sure that it's actually successfully importing pylab...

Comment: I removed the try part already...  nothing is shown....

Comment: @VacassalAlsk there are multiple backends available on Mac. It's likely that yours is not correctly set up. What does it output if you run `python -c "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_backend())"` in Terminal

Comment: @mfitzp, I get agg. Thank you.

Comment: @VacassalAlsk try the answer below. If that doesn't work there is something wrong with your setup which we can hopefully figure out

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable an interactive backend to get a plot viewer window when using `pylab.show()`. The 'agg' backround is non-interactive (although there are interactive backends based on Agg, e.g. TkAgg, Qt5Agg).

You have a few options, but the simplest option for MacOS X is the 'macosx' backend. You can enable this by using the following at the top of your script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('macosx')
```

Comment: I tried this without success ... one more important issue is that, the source code is for distribution purpose, so I could not modify it (since it would also need to be used on linux etc.) It would be more meaningful for me to correct  that in my machine....

Answer (score 0):

I just do the clean reinstall and things seem good now

http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html